# how can I separate instances of stand alone characters from a string field

Tags: sql, database, oracle

hopefully I can explain my question correctly.  I have a varchar2 field that has a description of things.  Some of the things have a descriptor attached to them based on a stand alone letter/number.  My question is how can I separate the stand alone instances of letters/numbers from the main text field? I have provided a simple example of what I am looking for.

```
+-------------+
| Things      |
---------------
|Structure A  |
|House B      |
|His Tent C   |
|Her canoe 1  |
|My Big Shoe  |
|My Big Shoe 7|
---------------

+-------------------------------------+
| Thingss     |  col 1       |  col 2 |
---------------------------------------
|Structure A  | Structure    |   A    |
|House B      | House        |   B    |
|C His Tent   | His Tent     |   C    |
|Her canoe 1  | Her canoe    |   1    |
|My Big Shoe  | My Big Shoe  |        |
|My Big Shoe 7| My Big Shoe  |   7    |
---------------------------------------
```

If the thing does not have a stand alone alpha numeric value, then it returns a null in the col 2 field.  Also please keep in mind, that the stand alone character may not always be at the end of the string.  Thank you.

Comment: can you have more than one standalone character? if so, which one would you pick in that case?

Comment: I have the same question as vkp. In addition, what do you want to do with My Big Shoe 11?  Is 11 a "standalone character"? Clearly it is not a single character, but just making sure you don't need to change the question after you already have a few answers.

Comment: And, presumably, the "standalone character" may also be in the middle of the string, not only at the beginning or the end, right?

Comment: mathguy, you are correct in that I didn't address things.  My dataset does not have instances where there are numeric values greater then 2; I put the 7 on there just as an example.  But I do see your point as right after I posted, I found an instance of a roman numeral II.  I only have about 4 instances out of ~20k, but it would still be nice to be able to identify those in the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract a stand alone character

```
select  Things
       ,regexp_replace(Things,'(^| )(.)( |$)','\1\3')      as col1
       ,regexp_substr (Things,'(^| )(.)( |$)',1,1,null,2)  as col2

from    t
;
```

---

Extract roman numerals

```
select  Things
       ,regexp_replace(Things,'(^| )([IVX]+)( |$)','\1\3')      as col1
       ,regexp_substr (Things,'(^| )([IVX]+)( |$)',1,1,null,2)  as col2

from    t
;
```

Comment: I guess this query can't handle standalone letters in the middle and on the start of the string?

Comment: @valex, Do you nees such solution?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Topic starter needs this: "Also please keep in mind, that the stand alone character may not always be at the end of the string. "

Comment: Is it possible to define roman numerals into this somehow?  To look for cases where there is a II, III, etc?

Comment: @user7002207, is it always roman numerals (can we forget about A,B,1,2 etc.)?

Comment: Thanks they both worked like a charm.  Is it possible to somehow combine them into one query?

Comment: Just use the output of one of them as input to the other (mobile...)

Answer (score 0):

Could be using INSTR

```
    SELECT 
            Things, 
            CASE 
              WHEN  length(SUBSTR(Things, INSTR(Things,' ',-1) + 1)) = 1 
                then SUBSTR(Things,1,INSTR(Things,' ',-1)) 
                else Things 
              end col1,
            CASE
              WHEN  length(SUBSTR(Things, INSTR(Things,' ',-1) + 1)) = 1 
                then SUBSTR(Things, INSTR(Things,' ',-1) + 1) 
                else NULL 
              end col2            
    FROM my_table
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected' error.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user7002207, I've fixed the code earlier, please check if you're using the right version.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Oracle `REGEXP_` functions. 
This query also process letters and digits **in the middle and in the start** of the string:

```
SELECT Things, 
       Trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(Things, '(\s|^)(\d|\S)(\s|$)',' ')) as Col1,
       Trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Things, '(\s|^)(\d|\S)(\s|$)')) as Col2
FROM Table1
```

<kbd>[Test Example](http://rextester.com/VNPBE7275)</kbd>

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (Things)
         VALUES ('A Structure')
    INTO Table1 (Things)
         VALUES ('Structure A')
    INTO Table1 (Things)
         VALUES ('House B')
    INTO Table1 (Things)
         VALUES ('His Tent C')
    INTO Table1 (Things)
         VALUES ('Her canoe 1')
    INTO Table1 (Things)
         VALUES ('My Big 8 Shoe')
    INTO Table1 (Things)
         VALUES ('My Big Shoe 7')
SELECT * FROM dual
\\

SELECT Things, 
       Trim(REGEXP_REPLACE(Things, '(\s|^)(\d|\S)(\s|$)',' ')) as Col1,
       Trim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Things, '(\s|^)(\d|\S)(\s|$)')) as Col2
FROM Table1
\\
```

RESULT

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════╗
║    THINGS     ║         Col1  ║         Col2 ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════╣
║ A Structure   ║ Structure     ║ A            ║
║ Structure A   ║ Structure     ║ A            ║
║ House B       ║ House         ║ B            ║
║ His Tent C    ║ His Tent      ║ C            ║
║ Her canoe 1   ║ Her canoe     ║ 1            ║
║ My Big 8 Shoe ║ My Big Shoe   ║ 8            ║
║ My Big Shoe 7 ║ My Big Shoe   ║ 7            ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════╝
```